# How to fix an error "You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “stdio.h" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I can not quit Xcode because of an error popping out: "You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “stdio.h” is in. You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes."

Answer (score 1):

Force Quit Xcode.
Menue -> Apple -> Force Quit
And yes, you are suposed to leave stdio.h as it is. (Not going into detail why this and a lot other files is protected.)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Force quitting XCode fixed the issue. I do not know why but it did.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.